# JavaScript Sort Table Data via Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am fetching data from a JSON file and rendering it to a table, but I need to sort it by ratings and votes with select options I've tried different ways but none of them worked.

This is a link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/natefr0st/596ew8zc/5/

I've tried to get the ratings with querySelectorAll and loop through each rating and then sort it but it didn't work, tried other different methods and again without result

```
const sortMenu = document.getElementById('sort');
sortMenu.addEventListener('change', sortTable);

function sortTable() {
    const rating = document.querySelectorAll('.rating')
    // rating.forEach((val, i) => console.log(val.innerHTML));

    // function compare(a, b) {
    //  return a.imdb_rating > b.imdb_rating ? 1 : -1;
    // }    

    if(sortMenu.value == 1) {
        rating.forEach(function(val, index) {
            let ratingArr = Array.from(val.innerHTML);
            return ratingArr.sort();
        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code base. FYI, I have tested it in your fiddle.

```
    let movies = [];
    const url = 'url';

   $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
        start(data, true)
    });

   function start(data, init=false) {
      movies = data
      displayMovies();
      if (init) {
          setPages();
      }
   }

    // Render 10 Rows Per Page
    // ========================
    function displayMovies(page = 1) {
        let movie_data = '';
        let max = page * 10;
        let min = max - 10;

        for (let i = min; i < max; i++) {
            let movie = movies[i];
            if (movie) {
                movie_data += `<tr class="movie-row">
                        <td scope="row">${movie.id}</td>
                        <td>${movie.title}</td>
                        <td>${movie.director}</td>
                        <td>${movie.distributor}</td>
                        <td class="rating">${movie.imdb_rating}</td>
                        <td class="votes">${movie.imdb_votes}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>`;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        $('#movies').html(movie_data);
    }

    // Render Pagination Buttons to the Table
    // =======================================
    function setPages() {
        let nbPages = Math.ceil(movies.length / 10);
        let pages = '';
        for (let i = 1; i <= nbPages; i++) {
            pages +=
                '<button class="btn btn-outline-info page-btn" type="button" page="' + i + '">Page ' + i + '</button>';
        }
        $('#pages').append(pages);
        $('.page-btn').click(function () {
            displayMovies($(this).attr('page'));
        });
    }

  // Sort Table TODO
    // ================
    const sortMenu = document.getElementById('sort');
    sortMenu.addEventListener('change', sortTable);

    function sortTable() {
        switch(parseInt(sortMenu.value)) {
            case 1:
                movies.sort((a, b) => (a.imdb_votes - b.imdb_votes));
                start(movies);
                break;
            case 2:
                movies.sort((a, b) => (b.imdb_votes - a.imdb_votes));
                start(movies);
                break;
            case 3: 
                movies.sort((a, b) => (a.imdb_rating - b.imdb_rating));
                start(movies);
                break;
            case 4:
                movies.sort((a, b) => (b.imdb_rating - a.imdb_rating));
                start(movies);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh but now renders the buttons for the pagination onchange many times :/

Comment: Done. please check.

Comment: FYI, I have added `init` flag in start function.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you explain it plz :}

Comment: Yes. Best way to sort it in your case is to sort array before init table. And when init table, setPages function is called only one time with status value of `init` flag.

Comment: It keeps doing that, now even without changing the option is initialized with a pair of buttons

Comment: Can you explain in details? I did not got it.

Comment: You are free to post another question if that is something critical issue.

Comment: Each time I select an option new set of pagination buttons appear at the bottom of the page even if I reload the page it starts with a pair of buttons

Before the buttons were : Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5 now is a pair and every time I select an options it doubles

Comment: It does not call setPages function and does not render buttons again.
You could check function.
function start(data, init=false) {
      movies = data
      displayMovies();
      if (init) {
          setPages();
      }
   }
After init, it's call start(movies); and init flag is equal to false. So it won't be call setPages() function again.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make your life easy by just using below.

Let jquery datatable plugin generate html for you you are creating your self, if 
below link fulfill your requirements this is best way.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: I am not allowed to use such tools

Comment: Ok in this case you have to add a row above TH of your columns with drop-down having on change click..on selected item change just call api again with order by selected value.